# Increment message per second in Python

Tags: python, range, message, increment

I have been banging my head against the wall for 20 minutes now, the answer is properly really simply, I just cant seem to find out how to solve this issue.

I have a Client and a Server and i want the client to send 10 messages per second to the server.
Now this works fine, however the increment doesnt.
I want it to go:

message1, message 2, message 3..... message 16, message 17

and so on until I close the connection.
But it stops at 10 and then loops back to message 1, message 2 and so on.

My code:

```
def send_packages():
    print('Sending ' + packages_per_second + ' packages per second')
    while True:
        if int(packages_per_second) > int(max_packages_per_second):
            print('The server cannot  handle more than 25 packages per second')
            break
        elif int(packages_per_second) < 1:
            print('Please check config file and make sure the "max_packages" is larger than 0')
            break
        else:
            for i in range(int(packages_per_second)):
                message = 'Message #' + str(i)
                sock.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
        sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't limiting how quickly the messages are actually sent; you are simply pausing for a second between batches of messages. To accurately limit your rate, you need to know how long it actually takes to send a message, then long enough that that the number packages plus the individual sleep periods add up to one second. For sake of simplicity (and given your low package rate), let's assume messages are sent instantaneously. Then you would want a loop like

```
from itertools import count

def send_packages():
    print(f"Sending {packages_per_second} packages per second")
    delay = 1 / packages_per_second
    for i in count():
        message = f'Message #{i}'
        sock.sendto(message.encode(), server_address)
        sleep(delay)
```

If `package_per_second` is 10, you'll sleep for 0.1 seconds between *every* message.